# Single vs Multiple Classes

Tags: html, css

Curious what strategy would be considered better:

One large class per element that contains everything.
vs
Multiple smaller classes all containing pieces.

Comment: Both. Neither. It depends. This isn't something that can be sanely generalised.

Comment: I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) would apply here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in general : multiple smaller

like " bold red underline dim"

cause if tomorrow you want to change the style of red to more red then you do it in one place - the red class

but it depends...

Comment: I see your point and I considered that, but could always ctrl+f replace the color code.

Comment: you dont work like that with CTRL F , in mega sytes where there is a possible mistake ... and if the CTRL f has stopped in the middle by error or computer stuck ? you won know what already replaced. you should do it in one centrelized place.

Comment: In general … classes describe what something is, not how it should look. Otherwise you might as well just use a style attribute.

Comment: i disagree , it depends. if by mouse over you want in jquery to add him color , you wont build a whole new class attributes with all the properties with the new red color.... you just add him the red css. ( "red" is alias fot the style color red...)

Comment: No, I'd add a `hover` class so that I wouldn't have to change every use of `red` if I changed the colour scheme to use blue.

Comment: Ah I didn't think about addClass/removeClass in jQuery and how multiple classes would be beneficial for that.

Comment: @ Quentin   - the hover was just an example . maybe i want to do by click or keyPress - add the red color / class. now lets see you do it with css only.

Comment: @Fase - beneficial  is the correct term. be smart not right . ( specially for future purpose)

Comment: You still give the class a name that describes the *state*, not the appearance. There is nothing wrong with using multiple classes on an element. The problem is when you use classes that describe how something should look instead of what it is. It throws away the benefits of separating style from content. If you decide that you want the element to have a border as well as being red, then you have to add a "has-a-border" class to every element that you want to change … or have a class called "red" that means "is red and has a border" (until you decide it should be blue with a border).

Comment: In general i Agree. but when you do a lot of JS and style changing - i believe that this is the right approach. if its fixed and never gonna be changed and not dynamic - go for it. but in my sites( built a lot) - im doing this with smallers. ( only the Dynamics !!!) i mean that if  its something blocked and const - i use like your approach. but if its dynamic styled - so only the littles.

Comment: @ Quentin  , tmorrow you wan to change all the red color to more red color - what you do ? this is a pron and cons.  i prefer the dynamics. with littles ( wherever needed)

Comment: I'd just change the stylesheet (if it is a big project where colours get reused a lot, I'd do so by editing the `$color-highlight` variable in the template I build the stylesheet from). What happens what you want to change all the red colour to a blue colour? Do you change the stylesheet and the HTML (wherever you have set the class) and the JavaScript (everywhere you dynamically change the class)?